# Jade+Express: Where does my client side Javascript go?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Where do I put my client side Javascript? I tried including it in my jade template like so:

```
script(type="type/javascript",src="../typeahead.js")
```

It returned this `Cannot GET /typeahead.js`

I also tried `require('../typeahead.js')` which unsurprisingly did not work. Just to clarify since I am new to `Node.js`, `require` is for server side code correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can go wherever you want.  You must write code to serve it.

Since you're using Express, there is a "static" module built-in for serving files on disk.  Use it like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  // 'public'; is your directory for static files
```

Remember that with Node.js, you're generally writing the server.  There are not set ways of doing things for web apps... there is no requirement that you're even building a web app.  Everything it up to you.  There are common modules for common tasks (such as Express/Connect) but in the end it's up to you.

`require` is part of the Node.js API and doesn't work in a browser.  However, there is always Require.js and Browserify.

Comment: So to clarify, I'd have to serve it using that line, and then link it to the jade template correct?

Comment: If you want to serve js/mine.js it would go in public/js/mine.js in your server. Any static files are served directly. your line in a jade template would look like this `script(src="js/mine.js")` to include the file. Hopefully your not thinking of directly creating javascript using jade

Comment: I did try that, didn't work until I followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9600305/765409